# Requesting rolled values on arbitrary dates and requesting ranges without specific start/end dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of questions on date sampling within a dataframe. Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.bdate_range('2014-01-01', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), index=dates)
```

yields this data frame:

```
2014-01-01   0
2014-01-02   1
2014-01-03   2
2014-01-06   3
2014-01-07   4
2014-01-08   5
2014-01-09   6
2014-01-10   7
2014-01-13   8
2014-01-14   9
```

1) If I want to get a forward rolled value for a date that is not available within the index, how would I do it? As an example:

```
df['2014-01-04']
```

yields a KeyError. However, I'd like to get the value 2, as a rolled forward value. Is there a way to request this easily, maybe something like df['2014-01-04', roll=FORWARD] ?

2) I'd also like to be able to request ranges, regardless of whether my start or end points are spot-on. Oddly enough, this works when requesting a range, e.g.:

```
df['2014-01-01':'2014-01-05']
```

yields:

```
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
```

However, it does not work when using .loc, e.g. df.loc['2014-01-01':'2014-01-05'] breaks. Is it possible to get .loc working in the same manner?

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it:

1) Using slicing (with `.loc` or `.ix` if using MultiIndex or slicing on both axes):

```
df[df.index < '2014-01-04'] # change '<' to '>' to have forward going dates.

            0
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
```

2) Using `query`:

```
df.query('"2014-01-01" < index < "2014-01-05"')
            0
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  2
```

both ways can be used to address both of your points.